# Is it possible to detect the time difference between the moment an epoll is generated by the kernel and the moment the Sun JVM reads it?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, nio, epoll

i.e. Time A = voltage hits the NIC; Time B = Selector from Java NIO package is able to select socket channel for I/O.

Comment: You could determine the time from the line being set to it reaching the JVM empirically. I doubt there is a way to do so purely in software. If you're only interested in how much time it spends gaffing around in the kernel, you could compile a kernel to log timestamps and look at those.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [SO_TIMESTAMP](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) and find a NIC that actually supports timestamps and one that supports timestamps with better than millisecond resolution.  Then you should have a chance if you can get Java to read incoming [`cmsg`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/cmsg) ancillary data.

Without good hardware support the packets are going to be tagged by the kernel with most likely a low resolution unstable timer.

**(edit #1)** Example code in C requiring 2.6.30 or newer kernel I think:

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c

**(edit #2)** Example code to determine kernel to user-space latency in C:

http://vilimpoc.org/research/ku-latency/

**(edit #3)** I recommend following the J-OWAMP project which is dependent upon high resolution timers and packet latency testing.  The OWAMP team have been pushing the Linux kernel team for better SO_TIMESTAMP support.

http://www.av.it.pt/jowamp/

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use something like [tcpdump](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) and then correlate timestamps between your application logs and the "sniffer" logs to determine this, it's not possible from the jvm alone.